# Provide task inputs based on variable populated by dependent task

Tags: gradle, groovy

**Use Case**

We've setup a pre-commit git hook that lints declarative pipelines (Jenkinsfiles). Currently all Jenkinsfiles in the repository are linted every time `git commit` is issued. I am looking to improve the process by only linting Jenkinsfiles that have changed since the last Gradle execution. We are using Gradle (v7.5.1) to orchestrate tasks like [Spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless) check/apply and [Jenkinsfile linting](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#linter).

**Example**

I've registered two tasks in build.gradle. One task rounds up all Jenkinsfiles in the repository and the other lints them. For the purposes of brevity I've simplified the tasks listed below.

```
def jenkinsfiles = []

task getJenkinsfiles {
    doLast {
        jenkinsfiles = ['Jenkinsfile1', 'Jenkinsfile2', 'Jenkinsfile3']
        //println(jenkinsfiles)
    }
}

task lintJenkinsfiles {
    dependsOn getJenkinsfiles
    inputs.file(jenkinsfiles)
    outputs.file('lintJenkinsfile.cache')
    doLast {
        println(jenkinsfiles)
    }
}
```

**Results**

`getJenkinsfiles` executes first without issue. If I uncomment `println(jenkinsfiles)` in `getJenkinsfiles` task, the value is printed to the console. However, `lintJenkinsfiles` fails and states that the `path may not be null or empty string. path='[]'`.

How does one reference a variable populated in task1 as an input in task2?

Comment: This question seems to be about writing code in Groovy, which makes the [tag:groovy] tag more appropriate. On the Git side of things all Git can help you with is `git diff --name-status` between any given set of commits; you'd need to know the last commit where things were checked.

Comment: Thanks @torek. I was able to develop a task that was inspired by your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following task that's inspired by Torek's comment on my original question. Also note that I consolidated the two tasks into one so that the Groovy script was processed before `inputs` and `outputs`.

1. Get all changed files using `git status --porcelain`. Split the result by newline.
2. Iterate over each entry. Each entry will be in the format of `<status> <filename>` (i.e., `M  test.txt`,  `M test.txt`, `MM test.txt`). See the [`git-status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format) page for more information.
3. If the entry's key (status) does not contain 'D' (deleted), add it to the `jenkinsfiles` list.

```
task lintJenkinsfiles {
    def jenkinsfiles = []
    def statusFileEntries = 'git status --porcelain'.execute().text.split('\n')
    for (def statusFileEntry : statusFileEntries) {
        def statusFileEntryCapture = statusFileEntry =~ /^\s{0,1}(\w{1,2})\s{1,2}(.*Jenkinsfile)$/
        if (statusFileEntryCapture.matches() && !statusFileEntryCapture[0][1].contains('D')) {
            jenkinsfiles += statusFileEntryCapture[0][2].trim()
        }
    }
    inputs.files(jenkinsfiles)
    outputs.file('lintJenkinsfiles.cache')
    doLast {
        if (!jenkinsfiles.isEmpty()) {
            println("Linting: ${jenkinsfiles}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: for interpreting `git status` output with machine code, use `git status --porcelain` or `git status --porcelain=v2`. The old v1 output *is* the `--short` output, really, so it's kind of the same thing, but using the right flag will future-proof your code against Git updates.